# Right Left Join, does it work on sub-queries oracle

Tags: sql, join, oracle11g, subquery

I have two tables as follows:

**loy_credits_ledger**

```
+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| CRL_OUTLET_CODE | CRL_REDEEM_MONTH | crl_redeem_year | CRL_RM_REDEEMED |
+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|       144000581 | APR              |            2014 | 273.3           |
|       144000581 | JUL              |            2014 | 194.1           |
|       144000581 | OCT              |            2014 | 216.3           |
|       144000581 | JAN              |            2015 | 24.9            |
|       144000581 | JAN              |            2015 | 177.1           |
+-----------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

**jti_qtr_credit_data**

```
+-----------------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+---------------------+
| QCD_OUTLET_CODE | QCD_YEAR | QCD_QUARTER | QCD_CREDIT | QCD_POINTS | QCD_CREDITS_BALANCE |
+-----------------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+---------------------+
|       144000581 |     2014 | Q1          | 273.3      |      54660 |                   0 |
|       144000581 |     2014 | Q2          | 194.1      |      38820 |                   0 |
|       144000581 |     2014 | Q3          | 378.8      |      75760 |                   0 |
|       144000581 |     2014 | Q4          | 202        |      40400 |                   0 |
|       144000581 |     2015 | Q1          | 321.55     |      64310 |                   0 |
+-----------------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+---------------------+
```

I need to join these two tables with some conditions. Apart from the messy tables structures (out of my control), I managed to get my results almost correct. Basically, this is my goal:

```
+-----------------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
| QCD_OUTLET_CODE | QCD_YEAR | QCD_QUARTER | QCD_POINTS | QCD_CREDIT | QCD_REDEEMED | QCD_CREDITS_BALANCE |
+-----------------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
|       144000581 |     2014 | Q2          |      38820 | 194.1      | 194.1        | 0                   |
|       144000581 |     2014 | Q4          |      40400 | 202        | 202          | 0                   |
|       144000581 |     2014 | Q1          |      54660 | 273.3      | 273.3        | 0                   |
|       144000581 |     2014 | Q3          |      75760 | 378.8      | 216.3        | 162.5               |
+-----------------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
```

It is just lacking the fifth record, which present in *jti_qtr_credit_data* only.

I did that using the script:

```
SELECT Q.QCD_OUTLET_CODE,  Q.QCD_YEAR, Q.QCD_QUARTER, Q.QCD_POINTS, Q.QCD_CREDIT,   nvl(SUM(L.REDEEMED), 0) AS QCD_REDEEMED, Q.QCD_CREDIT - NVL(SUM(L.REDEEMED),0) AS QCD_CREDITS_BALANCE
FROM 
(SELECT 
(case when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'JAN' Then 'Q4'
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'FEB' Then 'Q4'
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'MAR' Then 'Q4'
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'APR' Then 'Q1'
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'MAY' Then 'Q1'
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'JUN' Then 'Q1'
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'JUL' Then 'Q2'
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'AUG' Then 'Q2'
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'SEP' Then 'Q2'
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'OCT' Then 'Q3'
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'NOV' Then 'Q3'
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'DEC' Then 'Q3'
              ELSE NULL END) QUARTER, 

              (case 
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'JAN' Then crl_redeem_year-1
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'FEB' Then crl_redeem_year-1
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'MAR' Then crl_redeem_year-1
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'APR' Then crl_redeem_year
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'MAY' Then crl_redeem_year
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'JUN' Then crl_redeem_year
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'JUL' Then crl_redeem_year
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'AUG' Then crl_redeem_year
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'SEP' Then crl_redeem_year
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'OCT' Then crl_redeem_year
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'NOV' Then crl_redeem_year
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'DEC' Then crl_redeem_year
              ELSE NULL END) redeem_year,

              CRL_OUTLET_CODE,  CRL_CREDITS_EARNED, NVL(CRL_RM_REDEEMED, 0) REDEEMED
FROM loy_credits_ledger
where TO_CHAR(crl_redeem_year) is not null
AND CRL_OUTLET_CODE = 144000581
--GROUP BY CRL_REDEEM_MONTH, crl_redeem_year, CRL_OUTLET_CODE, CRL_CREDITS_EARNED
) L
full outer JOIN jti_qtr_credit_data Q 
ON L.CRL_OUTLET_CODE = Q.QCD_OUTLET_CODE
AND L.redeem_year = Q.QCD_YEAR
AND L.QUARTER =  Q.QCD_QUARTER
AND L.CRL_OUTLET_CODE = 144000581
GROUP BY Q.QCD_OUTLET_CODE,  Q.QCD_YEAR, Q.QCD_QUARTER, Q.QCD_YEAR, Q.QCD_CREDIT, Q.QCD_POINTS;
```

Now, the problem is, I tried *left* and *right* join. Since I have a record with QCD_Quarter = Q1 & QCD_Year = 2015 in *jti_qtr_credit_data*, but not in *loy_credits_ledger*; should not still show a record with null values with left or right join?

Does this problem have anything to do with sub-query with join?

Comment: When OUTER JOIN, (usually) all conditions should be in the ON clauses, not in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @jarlh if you are referring to `WHERE CRL_OUTLET_CODE = 144000581`, I added this to test one study case. I have hundreds of records in each table

Comment: yes, that one, put it in the ON clause instead! (When in WHERE, that join is executed as a regular inner join.)

Comment: @jarlh I updated my script. Thanks, I did not know that. But still giving me the same result

Answer (score 0):

By using (+) sign within normal *WHERE* condition to tell the DB to include all non-matching rows with NULL values; I managed to get the desired result.

The following is the script after amendment:

```
SELECT Q.QCD_OUTLET_CODE,  Q.QCD_YEAR, Q.QCD_QUARTER, Q.QCD_POINTS, Q.QCD_CREDIT,   nvl(SUM(L.REDEEMED), 0) AS QCD_REDEEMED, Q.QCD_CREDIT - NVL(SUM(L.REDEEMED),0) AS QCD_CREDITS_BALANCE
FROM 
(SELECT 
(case when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'JAN' Then 'Q4'
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'FEB' Then 'Q4'
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'MAR' Then 'Q4'
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'APR' Then 'Q1'
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'MAY' Then 'Q1'
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'JUN' Then 'Q1'
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'JUL' Then 'Q2'
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'AUG' Then 'Q2'
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'SEP' Then 'Q2'
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'OCT' Then 'Q3'
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'NOV' Then 'Q3'
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'DEC' Then 'Q3'
              ELSE NULL END) QUARTER, 

              (case 
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'JAN' Then crl_redeem_year-1
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'FEB' Then crl_redeem_year-1
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'MAR' Then crl_redeem_year-1
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'APR' Then crl_redeem_year
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'MAY' Then crl_redeem_year
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'JUN' Then crl_redeem_year
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'JUL' Then crl_redeem_year
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'AUG' Then crl_redeem_year
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'SEP' Then crl_redeem_year
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'OCT' Then crl_redeem_year
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'NOV' Then crl_redeem_year
              when CRL_REDEEM_MONTH = 'DEC' Then crl_redeem_year
              ELSE NULL END) redeem_year,

              CRL_OUTLET_CODE,  CRL_CREDITS_EARNED, NVL(CRL_RM_REDEEMED, 0) REDEEMED
FROM loy_credits_ledger
where TO_CHAR(crl_redeem_year) is not null
AND CRL_OUTLET_CODE = 144000581
--GROUP BY CRL_REDEEM_MONTH, crl_redeem_year, CRL_OUTLET_CODE, CRL_CREDITS_EARNED
) L
    ,
jti_qtr_credit_data q
where L.CRL_OUTLET_CODE(+) = Q.QCD_OUTLET_CODE
AND L.redeem_year(+) = Q.QCD_YEAR
AND L.QUARTER(+) =  Q.QCD_QUARTER
and q.QCD_OUTLET_CODE = 144000581
    GROUP BY Q.QCD_OUTLET_CODE,  Q.QCD_YEAR, Q.QCD_QUARTER, Q.QCD_YEAR, Q.QCD_CREDIT, Q.QCD_POINTS;
```

**Result**

```
+-----------------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
| QCD_OUTLET_CODE | QCD_YEAR | QCD_QUARTER | QCD_POINTS | QCD_CREDIT | QCD_REDEEMED | QCD_CREDITS_BALANCE |
+-----------------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
|       144000581 |     2014 | Q2          |      38820 | 194.1      | 194.1        | 0                   |
|       144000581 |     2014 | Q4          |      40400 | 202        | 202          | 0                   |
|       144000581 |     2014 | Q1          |      54660 | 273.3      | 273.3        | 0                   |
|       144000581 |     2014 | Q3          |      75760 | 378.8      | 216.3        | 162.5               |
|       144000581 |     2015 | Q1          |      64310 | 321.55     | 0            | 321.55              |
+-----------------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+--------------+---------------------+
```

This method is inspired by [this](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_subq_rewrite.htm) and [this](http://www.pscustomizer.com/sql-examples/outer-join-records-sub-query/) articles.